# how to delay a popup page?

Tags: ios

I just built an Activity indicator view, and a popup page in Xcode. How can I get a 3 second delay in Activity indicator view, then switch to popup page?

here is my Viewcontroller.m

```
- (IBAction)Connect:(UIButton *)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
  [self performSelector:@selector(delay2) withObject:Nil afterDelay:6.0];
  [self performSelector:@selector(delay1) withObject:ConnectAct afterDelay:0.0];
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"LP01;" message:@"No Connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Help", nil];
  [alert show];
}

- (IBAction)ConnectLP02:(UIButton *)sender 
{
  [self performSelector:@selector(delay2) withObject:Nil afterDelay:6.0];
  [self performSelector:@selector(delay1) withObject:ConnectAct afterDelay:0.0];
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"LP02;" message:@"No Connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Help", nil];
  [alert show];
}

- (void)delay1 {
  ConnectAct.alpha = 1.0;    
}

- (void)delay2 {

}
```

Comment: What is `ConnectAct`?  Which page you want to pop to? Have you set up it?

Comment: yes ,i already made the UIAlert,but the Activity indicator view show in same time,haven't delay 6 second...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)ConnectLP02:(UIButton *)sender 
{
  [self performSelector:@selector(delay2) withObject:Nil afterDelay:6.0];
  [self performSelector:@selector(delay1) withObject:ConnectAct afterDelay:0.0];

}

- (void)delay1 {
  ConnectAct.alpha = 1.0;    
}

- (void)delay2 {
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"LP02;" message:@"No Connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Help", nil];
  [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot~~it worked!! 
And sorry for one more question,in my situation,how can the Activity indicator view dismiss??Thanks a lot~

Comment: Is `ConnectAct` the Activity indicator? Can you show more code about it? try `[ConnectAct setHidden:YES]` or `[ConnectAct stopAnimating]`.You should read the apple developer document in detail.

Comment: i already used ConnectAct.stopAnimating, It worked,but i got a yellow Flat,it tell me "Property access result unused - getters should not be used for side effects",What thing i am wrong?
Thanks~

Comment: remove the dot. dot mean accessing the property.Look carefully at my comment.

Comment: just fix the problem,i forget to add [] there~thanks a lot~
but got a new problem again~
Sorry for many Question,
after first time the Activity indicator run and dismiss,
when i press button again,it keep dismiss and haven't show it again..
ddi i need used if?
Thanks~

Comment: Check up the UIActivityIndicator class, you will see a instance method call startAnimating.Just call it in you viewController. So, you'd better read the document. Apple Developer Document is a very very important way to learn Cocoa.

Comment: Thanks a lot,fix the problem~and i will read the apple developer document deeper~^^